# AngularJS: Non-destructive, non-blocking form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, autosave, dirty-data

## problem

Assume I have a form with multiple inputs that bind to various properties of a view's data object.  As I tab out ('blur') I want to persist that value to a save service and move on to the next field to edit.  This save service returns the newly saved object in full.  If I then write the updated object to the controller's data object, the current input that I am editing will lose changes.

## question

Is there an built-in Angular solution using `ngFormController` that I am missing?  Are there any libraries that support this without having a per-input type scenario?

I'm really hoping to avoid doing something like:

```
<input name="field1" save-on-blur="vc.save('field1')">
```

...and then having to *diff* the current view model against the incoming view model.

Comment: I think you can use the validations directives.... have you tried this already?

Comment: These values do not require validation so we're not using them.  Could you provide an example of how using them would help solve this problem?